# lookbehind alternation in Java seems to be returning the longest result

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm looking to extract (using Java's built in Regex at the moment) text after a range of suffixes.
I'm using the lookbehind technique but the result I get always seems to be the longest result rather than the match of the first alternation group to match the prefix text.

That is,

```
(?<=Book name|Book).*
```

Given the text `"Book name Story"`

The match is always `"name Story"` regardless of which way round the regex alternation is.
My question here is what is the best way to get just the `"Story"` text without match any of the other text? 
In practice I'm hoping to limit the right hand side too with a lookahead(just in case that's pertinent).

Comment: why are you using OR in your regex pattern? What are other possibilities. mention other inputs as well.

Comment: why don't you try `str.split("\\s+")[2]`

Comment: Yea, it seems like you don't need the second `Book` in your alternation

Comment: try `str.replace("Book name ","")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a lookahead here.

```
(?<=Book name |Book )\S+(?=$)
```

OR

```
(?<=Book name )\S+|(?<=Book )(?!name)\S+
```

Java regex would be,

```
"(?<=Book name |Book )\\S+(?=$)"
```

OR

```
"(?<=Book name )\\S+|(?<=Book )(?!name)\\S+"
```

[DEMO 1](http://regex101.com/r/aM7dI4/6)

[DEMO 2](http://regex101.com/r/aM7dI4/8)

Code:

```
String s = "Book name Story";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=Book name |Book )\\S+(?=$)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(s);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
 String ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
 System.out.println(ResultString);
}//=> Story
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=Book name |Book )` Looknbehind sets the matching marker just after to the string `Book name` or `Book`.
- `\S+` Matches one or more non-space characters.
- `(?=$)` Lookahead asserts what following must be a line end.

Comment: Don't forget to mention what the lookahead is doing here

Comment: @skamazin added some explanation.

Comment: What if the input is `Book name Story of my life`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a possessive quantifier to force the subpattern in the lookbehind to be tested first with the word "name", example:

```
(?<=Book (?:name )?+)\S+
```

Note that it is a strange behaviour of the Java regex engine. It seems that the pattern is tested like : `(?:Book (?:name )?+)\S+` and that the regex engine forgets to give the first possible result. *(a "normal behavior" is supposed to give the first result on the left that is "name")*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a possessive quantifier *trick*:

```
(?<=(?:Book name |Book ){1}+).*
                        ^^^^
```

More details at http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html